# How to troubleshoot gitlab kubernetes runner accessing private registry

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a k8s git runner deployment which should access a private registry. However access is always failing:

```
Waiting for pod default/runner-6f15beb6-project-3046-concurrent-0xswl6 to be running, status is Pending
ERROR: Job failed: image pull failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://docker-registry/v2/image: unknown: Authentication is required
```

I have created the secret:

```
kubectl create secret docker-private ...

kubectl describe secrets docker-private
Name:         docker-private
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson

Data
====
.dockerconfigjson:  184 bytes
```

Use the secret in gitlab's `values.yml`:

```
runners:
  ...
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: docker-private
```

And have verified that its actually part of the gitlab release:

```
helm get sandbox | grep -C 5 docker

  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: docker-private
```

What else can be source of failed registry access?

Comment: Are you sure that you credentials are valid? Can you access registry manually?

Comment: Solved- had to use image: docker-registry/image, I was only using the image name